# Can ffmpeg extract the motion vectors from VP9 videos?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, video-encoding, vp9

And if it can, are the motion vectors similar to how they are in H264?

I ask because I can run a command like

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -flags2 +export_mvs -i "$1" -vf codecview=mv=pf+bf+bb /tmp/mot
    ion_vectors.mp4
```

then view it with VLC and see the motion vectors superimposed upon the video. If I try this with a VP9 encoded video I'm unable to see them.

Comment: The [wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Debug/MacroblocksAndMotionVectors) says "This option does not work for codecs which do not export motion vectors (most non-MPEG based codecs)". A quick look in `libavcodec` seems to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks for looking that up for me. Kind of a bummer though, what about programs that want to process motion from videos encoded in this codecs?

Comment: Wow, thank you again for the research! My Google-fu has been failing me this week.

Comment: Ok, so no dice. `vpxdec` used to support it for VP8 but the flags are removed in the master.